# Django: Email isn't sent in built-in PasswordResetView

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm overriding the built-in `PasswordResetView` but the email isn't sent. I'm currently using `django.core.mail.backends.console.EnailBackend` but the email's content doesn't show up on console.

My code is like this

```
class CustomPasswordResetView(PasswordResetView):
    email_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_email.html'
    form_class = CustomForm
    template_name = 'accounts/password_reset.html'
    subject_template_name = 'accounts/password_reset_subject.txt'
    title = 'Custom Title'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts/password_reset_done')
```

It redirects to the `password_reset_done` as expected but the email doesn't show on concole.
Is there something I missed? As long as I see the Django's code, I cannot find the part handling with sending email in `PasswordResetView` Do I have to write email functionality manually?

`forms.py`

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...

    def save(self, ...):
        super().save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that, the email is [sent from the form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1b49b792e9f0e6a5ae22f49f75586847e7e183bf/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L235), not the view. So if you are using `CustomForm`, its better to implement the send email method in the form like this:

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
  ...

  def send_mail(self):
     return send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@example.com',
        [self.cleaned_data.get('email')],
        fail_silently=False,
     )

   def is_valid(self):
      valid = super(CustomForm, self).is_valid()
      if valid:
         self.send_email()
      return valid
```

Or you can override from `PasswordResetForm` and put your customization there.

Comment: Actually I override `PasswordResetForm` as well. I still don't get why it doesn't work and I have to pur customization. Is it supposed to send email without overriding `send_mail`?

Comment: Ah I think I got it I need to override `save()` method. Thanks